# Форматирование ссылки, удаление всех параметров URI запроса

Tags: c#, строки

Как можно форматировать текст ссылки?

`https://scontent-hel3-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/160504348_760988724778706_2687122359348549904_n.jpg?tp=1&_nc_ht=scontent-hel3-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=102&_nc_ohc=2xJnijGZPRIAX-4jLOm&ccb=7-4&oh=6289e9f647f9e94015a7e641804813fb&oe=607F7980&_nc_sid=7bff83`

Чтобы можно было удалить весь оставшийся текст после расширения .jpg
Ссылки могут быть разными, но лишний текст нужно удалить.

Вариант типа `link.Replace("&tp=1&_nc_ht=scontent-hel3-1...", "");` не подойдет, так как ссылки могут быть разными. Нужно только очистить ссылку на файл от всего, что идет после расширения файла.

Comment: А что вам мешает использовать специально созданные для этого компоненты? Для ссылок это `Uri`, сделает ведь все за вас. Нечто на подобии `var uri = new Uri(url); var result = $"{uri.Scheme}://{uri.Host}{uri.AbsolutePath}";`.

Comment: Спасибо! То что надо.  Почему то решил, что ссылки надо форматировать как текст.

Comment: Почти все, что имеет свой стандарт, имеет для этого свои инструменты. Будь то кодировка, ссылка, JSON, XML, HTML и прочее прочее прочее. Так что, если видите популярный текст, который стандартизирован, то первым делом ищите инструменты по работе с ним, а уж затем думайте про регулярки, `Replace` и др.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод "в лоб", не рекомендую, а просто показываю

```
string url = "https://scontent-hel3-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/160504348_760988724778706_2687122359348549904_n.jpg?tp=1&_nc_ht=scontent-hel3-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=102&_nc_ohc=2xJnijGZPRIAX-4jLOm&ccb=7-4&oh=6289e9f647f9e94015a7e641804813fb&oe=607F7980&_nc_sid=7bff83";
Console.WriteLine(url.Split('?')[0]);
// или так
Console.WriteLine(url.Remove(url.IndexOf('?')));
```

А вот правильный метод:

```
var builder = new UriBuilder(url);
builder.Query = null;
Console.WriteLine(builder.Uri);
```

Вывод в консоль

```
https://scontent-hel3-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/160504348_760988724778706_2687122359348549904_n.jpg
```